# How to hide Electron.js frame?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I also looked for solutions to other problems, but they did not turn out as I wanted. How can I delete the top bar of the window, as I marked in the photo?
[photo]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

native APIs directly supports frameless windows. You need to pass the `frame` option false while creating new window. Here is the example.

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, frame: false })
win.show()
```

You can read more at [official docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/frameless-window)